# Application Crash and Seg fault

Tags: unix, crash, segmentation-fault

Do these two [App crash and segfault] terms refer to the same phenomenon? 
Or is it that SegFault is just one of the reason for Application crash.

I searched thr stackoverflow however did not get a clear answer. one relevant post is here. 
[Common Causes of Operating System Crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114081/common-causes-of-operating-system-crashes/114098#114098)

Comment: A seg fault is just one of many ways that an application can "crash".

Comment: Thanks Paul. I am curious to know what are other ways?

Comment: The list will be somewhat dependent on CPU architecture and choice of operating system.

Comment: Was curious to know for Intel architecture and for Linux OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dividing by zero is a reason an application can crash, but it's not a segmentation fault. And if you catch and repair a segmentation fault, it won't cause the application to crash.

Comment: Thanks David. This cleared my confusion. Is there any other reason for a crash?

Comment: There are tons of reasons for crashes. An assertion is one -- where the code encounters a condition the programmer told it should cause it to crash. Also, executing an illegal instruction, a floating point exception, division by zero, stack overflow, attempting direct I/O without appropriate privileges, and so on.